# How to create application id after converting facebook profile to official page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I made facebook profile long back and have created it to facebook page for business purpose. Now I need to access facebook API for programming, as per documentation I require application id for using facebook API, I am able to register in facebook developers but while creating apps it gives me below message.

> Not Authorized To Manage Apps: This account is not authorized to manage
>   apps. Please use your verified personal Facebook account to create and
>   manage your apps.

If I create application id in my personal account than how can I assign that application Id to my official page?

I have tried creating application Id in my personal account but sometimes FB.getLoginStatus() gives response as "not authorized" but some times it gives "not login".

Cant figure out the problem, Can anyone please help me?
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You create a the app using your personal account. Then you create a page access token which is explained as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens